# What is difference between Stack Overflow and Pro Webmasters?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, stack-exchange, scope

What kind of questions that matters about web(HTML, CSS, PHP, SEO, CMS, ... ) should posted at Stack Overflow and what at Pro Webmasters?

Comment: Have you read the FAQ for both sites?

Comment: @TheEstablishment Yes. I have, but i didn't see clear difference between explanations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I bumped into this the other day where some folks were trying to close a question about CSS and have it migrated to Pro Webmasters.

The FAQ states:

> If your question generally covers the operation of websites which you
>   control, then you’re in the right place to ask your question!
>
> Please note that if your question is about detailed HTML, JavaScript,
>   or CSS coding, it might be a better fit on Stack Overflow.

As a moderator, these are some guidelines I work with based on my interpretation of the FAQs and site-specific meta discourse:

CSS, HTML, Javascript, general markup are basically "Domain Specific Languages" and so can be considered as programming languages.

SEO however is on-topic for Pro Webmasters. Pro Webmasters is geared towards running a site as a "Webmaster/Administrator" i.e. site operations but not the minutia of the code or markup itself.

CMS questions are tricky. We already have two sites that deal specifically with [WordPress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) and [Drupal](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/) questions and answers so where to ask these questions is reasonably clear cut.

Other CMS systems where you have questions that are *programming related* should probably be asked on Stack Overflow.

CMS/E-Commerce App questions about the operation, administration and maintenance of your application are a bit of a grey area.

For example, questions about how to set tax rates, managing stock or maintaining content are very application specific and I'd say probably don't have a home anywhere on the Stack Exchange network at this time. There have been a number of [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) proposals for different CMS applications but none of these on their own have gained enough traction to reach any reasonable critical mass to survive. See: [CMS/BLOG proposals MERGER](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62/cms-blog-proposals-merger).

On the other hand, questions about sites that happen to have a CMS or E-Commerce application where you're asking an "operational" question about the site overall are probably on-topic.

The bottom line is, check a site's FAQ first. Then if you still can't decide, don't hesitate to ask on a site's meta about whether a question is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, StackOverflow is for the programming (actual development) for the sites, and ProWebmasters is for when the site is up-and-running. Don't forget there are other semi-related web SE sites, like WordPress Answers.